# How can I search only the selected options in multivalue react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a react-select component with 'All'/'Selected' tabs and a search bar in the menu:
[image: Dropdown with search bar - all values]

[image: Dropdown with search bar - selected values]

I am able to search the Options in the 'All' tab with no issues (filters correctly, shows noOptionsMessage if search input does not match any values)

I am having the following issues in 'Selected' tab:

- Viewing 'Selected' tab with no options does not display noOptionsMessage
  [image]
- Pressing spacebar in empty 'Selected' tab adds the last highlighted option from the 'All' tab
  [image]

after pressing space in 'Selected' tab

[image]

- Searching on empty list with input that matches values in 'All' tab results in no change and no noOptionsMessage displays
  [image]
- Searching with input that does NOT match values in 'All' tab results in TypeError: _props$children.filter is not a function

Here are the main subcomponents

```
const SearchInput = (props) => {
  const { searchPlaceholder } = props.selectProps

  return (
    <input
      className="search-input"
      type="text"
      placeholder={searchPlaceholder}
      value={props.selectProps.inputValue}
      onChange={(e) => {
        //onInputChange just runs a setInput function
        return props.selectProps.onInputChange(e.currentTarget.value, {
          action: 'input-change',
        })
      }}
      onMouseDown={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.target.focus()
      }}
      onTouchEnd={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.target.focus()
      }}
      // onMenuInputFocus set to const inputFocus = () => {return setIsFocused(true)}
      onFocus={props.selectProps.onMenuInputFocus}  
    />
  )
}
```

```
const MenuTab = ({
  tabName,
  isSelected,
  group,
  onClick = (_) => {
    return _
  },
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={`menu-tab ${isSelected ? 'selected-tab' : ''}`}>
      <label className="menu-tab-label" htmlFor={tabName}>
        {tabName}
        <input
          id={tabName}
          className="menu-tab-input"
          name={group}
          type="radio"
          value={tabName.toLowerCase()}
          checked={isSelected}
          onClick={() => {
            return onClick(tabName)
          }}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const MenuTabList = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('All')
  const { id, value, searchable } = props.selectProps

  return (
    <>
      {searchable && selectedTab === 'All' && (
        <div>
          <SearchInput {...props} />
        </div>
      )}
      <MenuList {...props}>
        <div className="tab-container">
          {['All', 'Selected'].map((el) => {
            return (
              <MenuTab
                tabName={el}
                group={id}
                onClick={() => {
                  return setSelectedTab(el)
                }}
                isSelected={selectedTab === el}
              />
            )
          })}
        </div>
        {selectedTab === 'All'
          ? props.children
          : props.children?.filter((opt) => {
              return value.includes(opt.props.data)
            })}
      </MenuList>
    </>
  )
}
```

I have tried moving the filtered options into their own array variable, and just returning an empty array if that happens to be of length 0, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

I believe I need to have the search input treat both lists as separate entities, but I can't think of how to do that without creating a second Select Component or at a minimum second Menu/MenuList component.

Answer (score 0):

I was making it more difficult than it needed to be. I just added a function that would only filter the selected values when search actually returned at least one value.

```
const MenuTabList = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('All')
  const { id, value, searchable } = props.selectProps
  const getSelectedValues = (allOptions) => {
    if (allOptions.length > 0) {
      return allOptions.filter((opt) => {
        return value.includes(opt.props.data)
      })
    }
    return null
  }

  return (
    <>
      {searchable && (
        <div>
          <SearchInput {...props} />
        </div>
      )}
      <MenuList {...props}>
        <div className="tab-container">
          {['All', 'Selected'].map((el) => {
            return (
              <MenuTab
                tabName={el}
                group={id}
                onChange={() => {
                  return setSelectedTab(el)
                }}
                isSelected={selectedTab === el}
              />
            )
          })}
        </div>
        {selectedTab === 'All'
          ? props.children
          : getSelectedValues(props.children)}
      </MenuList>
    </>
  )
}
```

Still working out how to prevent space from selecting the last highlighted option in the All tab, when currently in the Selected tab. seems like this even happens during searching as well